# Append array as column to dataframe (or create new dataframe according to other dataframe's date)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, series

First of all, I want to say that there's a lot of similar questions and I'm spending almost 2 days looking and try to solve my problem, using all of the functions but couldn't find what I need, even though I believe there's going to be a very simple solution.

Complete code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mt = pd.Series([34.678714, 34.087302, 33.857141, 33.250000,
           33.124999, 31.818181, 31.082676, 29.107807,
           30.144405], index=['2019-12-31', '2020-01-02',
                              '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06',
                              '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08',
                              '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10',
                              '2020-01-13'])

mn = np.array([ 7.76179772 16.68166719 23.3037243,  27.30909839, 29.68638615, 30.56226802, 30.77646665, 30.08922891, 30.11195783])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
print(mt)
print(mn)
mt.plot()
plt.show()
```

I get this [image: plot(1)]

And printing my results are:

```
print(mt)
Date
2019-12-31    34.678714
2020-01-02    34.087302
2020-01-03    33.857141
2020-01-06    33.250000
2020-01-07    33.124999
2020-01-08    31.818181
2020-01-09    31.082676
2020-01-10    29.107807
2020-01-13    30.144405

print(mn)
[ 7.76179772 16.68166719 23.3037243  27.30909839 29.68638615 30.56226802 30.77646665 30.08922891 30.11195783 ... ]
```

I need to add `mn` array to `mt`series and plot them all together with Date indices of `mt`. So it can look like this:
**(First Question is how to make merge series and array above, to make it look like below)**

```
    print(mt)
Date          actual      est
2019-12-31    34.678714  7.76179772 
2020-01-02    34.087302  16.68166719 
2020-01-03    33.857141  23.3037243  
2020-01-06    33.250000  27.30909839 
2020-01-07    33.124999  29.68638615 
2020-01-08    31.818181  30.56226802  
2020-01-09    31.082676  30.77646665 
2020-01-10    29.107807  30.08922891 
2020-01-13    30.144405  30.11195783
```

**Finally and more important question, how can I plot mt (with jumping dates) and mn (without date indices) together into like [image: this plot(2)]  (with x-axis as dates)**

I used hstack, join, append, insert, add, asarray and a lot others that cant even remember. Maybe used them wrong, open to all kind of answers really.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Really appreciate the time you put into searching for an existing answer. It's still really hard for us to help you, though, without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, you have a number of extra libraries, settings, and datasets in your code that don't seem necessary to the question. Any chance you could cut down your code to only the part that causes the plotting issue you're facing? It looks like the main issue may just relate to weekends in one series but not another? But it's hard to tell.

Comment: I tried to cut it down just so others could just copy-paste and run it but will edit now even better. The main issue that I get numpy.narray (mn) that has same length as time series or copy of dataframe (mt) and I want to add mn array as column to mt but code is gone through many calculations so that I can't even tell that if what mt actually is. I mean it has date indices and I can get mt.values but can't find a way to make it look like the last(second) plot image

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely heading in the right direction. If you can, create your data from scratch so we can start from the point right where the problem is. For example, `pd.Series([34.678714, 34.087302], index=['2019-12-31', '2019-12-31'])` gives the first two rows in one of your examples. I don't particularly want to install pandas_datareader and pykalman just to answer this question, and I imagine that's a common barrier to people helping with this q. Also, please embed the plots rather than linking to them.

Comment: No problem, I just thought that maybe some would show a different way with kalman etc. but now edited according to rules I think. Thanks for help. Got error about embed images, says I need 10 rep before able to embed images.

Comment: Just upvoted based on all the edits :) you should now have enough rep!

Comment: Thank you for helping me get started at this great community! Edited plots

Comment: ok I'm still a bit confused about the question. Is the issue just how to assign the values of mn as a column called "estimated" in the mt dataframe? If so, why don't the values in your expected results match the provided values for mn?

Comment: Yes, assigned it but more importantly plot them together with x-axis as mt dataframe indices. Values are stock/share prices and basically estimated ones are the prices that I'm guessing to be, so I need to see them when they're overlap or cross each other with exact dates

Comment: From the output image, we can see that your index contains strings, not datetime objects. Is this intended?

Comment: @Mr.T It was intended to simplify example, in the original I gone through few calculations and honestly can't even tell if my indices are strings or datetime objects anymore. I mean I was able to use pd.date_range function but can't use it for this code but even then since my date indices jumps weekends and holidays i couldn't implement data_range()

Comment: `print(df.index)` and `print(df.dtypes)` tell you what the data types of the index and columns of `df` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to use `pd.concat` like this:

```py
mt = pd.Series(
    [34.678714, 34.087302, 33.857141, 33.250000, 33.124999, 31.818181, 31.082676, 29.107807, 30.144405],
    index=['2019-12-31', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-13'],
    name='mt'  # Added for next step
)

mn = np.array([ 7.76179772, 16.68166719, 23.3037243, 27.30909839, 29.68638615, 30.56226802, 30.77646665, 30.08922891, 30.11195783])


# Combine data:
combined_data = pd.concat([
    mt,
    pd.Series(data=mn, index=mt.index, name='mn')
], axis=1)

#               mt          mn
# 2019-12-31    34.678714   7.761798
# 2020-01-02    34.087302   16.681667
# 2020-01-03    33.857141   23.303724
# 2020-01-06    33.250000   27.309098
# 2020-01-07    33.124999   29.686386
# 2020-01-08    31.818181   30.562268
# 2020-01-09    31.082676   30.776467
# 2020-01-10    29.107807   30.089229
# 2020-01-13    30.144405   30.111958

# Plot data:
combined_data.plot(marker='o', figsize=(12, 4.8))
```

Which generates this graph:[image]

An extra tip, you're currently using a string index, even though they represent dates. You can convert it to a `pd.DatetimeIndex` like this:

```py
$ combined_data.index = pd.to_datetime(combined_data.index)
$ combined_data.index

DatetimeIndex(['2019-12-31', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06',
               '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10',
               '2020-01-13'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

This function is also extremely helpful `pd.date_range`:

```py
$ pd.date_range('2019-12-31', '2020-01-13', freq='1B') # 1B = 1 business day
DatetimeIndex(['2019-12-31', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03',
               '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09',
               '2020-01-10', '2020-01-13'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```